# Java - How to detect PCI modem on window 7 (64bit)

Tags: java

I want to build the java application like callerID application.
When having an incoming call then this application will show phone number in the textbox.
I search on the internet, somebody said that using Java Communications API like this site.
Check it like at http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31915 
I have done the same step in that site but I get **NoSuchPortException** when get port "COM3".

```
CommPortIdentifier portId1 = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3");
```

My PCI modem was running fine when I'm testing by other callerID applicaiton.
Everyone know how to detect PCI modem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enumerate available ports on your system like here: http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/enumerating-serial-port-using-rxtx/.

Then connect modem and try one by one to get the port.

Comment: I used Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); but ports = null after that

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem with PCI modems. They are no HW but SW modems. Try to get a true serial modem (even USB). You will safe a lot of headache.

Comment: Do you know other way? because my PCI modem was running fine when I'm testing by other callerID applicaiton.

Comment: `other callerID applicaiton` is a Java program ?

Comment: I don't know what program language of that application. I used three app follow: http://www.phonetray.com/, http://www.janrufmonitor.de/downloads.html and http://www.jam-software.com/smartcallmonitor/?language=EN

Comment: If I remeber well, I got this running once in Linux with PCI modem & Java & RxTx. But too long ago ...